# Заполнение RecyclerView вызывает ошибку

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, recyclerview, arraylist, recyclerviewadapter

Код адаптера:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.stillhet.R;
import com.example.stillhet.StatesForAdapter.DiscussionState;

import java.util.List;

public class DiscussionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscussionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<DiscussionState> adapter;
    private final OnStateClickListener onClickListener;

    public DiscussionAdapter(Context context, List<DiscussionState> adapter, OnStateClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DiscussionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public interface OnStateClickListener{
        void onStateClick(DiscussionState state, int position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DiscussionAdapter.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        DiscussionState state = adapter.get(position);
        holder.Head.setText(state.getHead());
        holder.Theme.setText(state.getDiscussTheme());
        holder.Creator.setText(state.getBody());
        holder.Body.setText(state.getCreator());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> onClickListener.onStateClick(state,position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapter.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView Head, Theme, Creator, Body;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            Head = view.findViewById(R.id.discussion_title);
            Theme = view.findViewById(R.id.Discuss_Theme);
            Creator = view.findViewById(R.id.Discuss_Creator);
            Body = view.findViewById(R.id.disc_body);
        }
    }
}
```

Код state:

```
public class DiscussionState {
    private String Head, discussTheme, Body, Creator;

    public DiscussionState(String head, String theme, String body, String creator) {
        this.Head = head;
        this.discussTheme = theme;
        this.Body = body;
        this.Creator = creator;
    }

    public String getHead() { return this.Head; }

    public void setHead(String head) { this.Head = head; }

    public String getDiscussTheme() { return this.discussTheme; }

    public void setDiscussTheme(String discussTheme) { this.discussTheme = discussTheme; }

    public String getBody() { return this.Body; }

    public void setBody(String body) { this.Body = body; }

    public String getCreator() { return this.Creator; }

    public void setCreator(String creator) { this.Creator = creator; }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.stillhet.Adapter.DiscussionAdapter;
import com.example.stillhet.R;
import com.example.stillhet.StatesForAdapter.DiscussionState;
import com.example.stillhet.databinding.FindDiscussionFragmentBinding;
import com.example.stillhet.Сlasses.Discussion;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindDiscussionFragment extends Fragment {

    FindDiscussionFragmentBinding binding;

    ArrayList<DiscussionState> states = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> head;
    ArrayList<String> theme;
    ArrayList<String> creator;
    ArrayList<String> body;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FindDiscussionFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        states.add(new DiscussionState ( "head", "theme", "body", "creator"));

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.Find_discuss);
        DiscussionAdapter discussionAdapter = new DiscussionAdapter(FindDiscussionFragment.this.getContext(), states, null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(discussionAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Разметка строк RecyclerView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/song_row"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:targetApi="honeycomb">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ikon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/disk"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/discussion_title"
        android:layout_width="281dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="Head"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/disc_body"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Discuss_Creator"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:text="body" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/disc_body"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:text="Создатель:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discussion_title"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ikon"
        android:text="Тема:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Discuss_Theme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/discussion_title"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="Theme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Discuss_Creator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Discuss_Theme"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="Creator" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.Discussion.FindDiscussionFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MyDiscussion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="MyDiscussionClick"
            android:text="@string/myDiscussion"
            android:textColor="#777676"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CreateDiscussion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="MyDiscussionClick"
            android:text="@string/createDiscussion"
            android:textColor="#777676"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FindDiscussion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="MyDiscussionClick"
            android:text="@string/findDiscussion"
            android:textColor="#C33D13"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/FindWithHead"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.033"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Find_discuss"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="641dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И ошибка:

```
2022-03-27 18:28:29.506 13401-13401/com.example.stillhet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stillhet, PID: 13401
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.stillhet.Adapter.DiscussionAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DiscussionAdapter.java:43)
        at com.example.stillhet.Adapter.DiscussionAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DiscussionAdapter.java:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:2122)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1263)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
2022-03-27 18:28:29.509 13401-13401/com.example.stillhet E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-03-27 18:28:29.552 13401-13401/com.example.stillhet I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13401 SIG: 9
```

Не могу понять что именно вызывает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас NPE - RecyclerView - null.

Почему - ясно из вашего кода:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.Find_discuss);
    DiscussionAdapter discussionAdapter = new DiscussionAdapter(getActivity(), states, null);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(discussionAdapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_discussion_fragment, container, false);
}
```

В нём вы ищете RecyclerView в активити (а он, скорее всего, во фрагменте). В итоге получаете null. Помимо этого вы делаете это до того, как разметку фрагмента (где, скорее всего и находится RecyclerView) загружаете.

Вам надо сделать следующее:

> Искать RecyclerView не в активити, но в разметке фрагмента. Например в аргументе `view` в методе `onViewCreated`